# What kind of object is "people" in "He looks down on people"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, objects

Is *people* in *he looks down on people* a direct object or an object of a preposition?

I'm confused because *looks down on* is a phrasal verb, which should mean that *on* isn't a preposition.

Comment: Why should it mean "on" isn't a preposition? It certainly is a preposition.

Comment: Does that mean that "on" is NOT part of the phrasal verb?

Comment: [In English traditional grammar, a phrasal verb is the combination of two or three words from different grammatical categories — a verb and a particle, such as an adverb or a preposition — to form a single semantic unit on a lexical or syntactic level.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb)

Comment: It's still a verb followed by a preposition, but they are a single semantic unit.

Comment: Oh, so "on" functions as both a phrasal verb AND a preposition. I thought it was an either/or situation. So that means that "people" is an object of a preposition.